# How can I allow anonymous access to OTRS FAQ area?

Tags: permissions, perl

I have been searching for this for quite some time now. I am using OTRS 2.4.7 and installed the FAQ package version 1.6.5.

Everything seems to work fine. When I am logged in, I can create articles and other users have the ability to browse the articles.

I want to be able to allow access to any anonymous non-user to be able to read these articles.

Can anyone shed some light on how to allow this type of access?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

In OTRS there will be a public front end for FAQ's available at http://otrs.example.org/otrs/public.pl - for this no authentication is neccesary.

In order for FAQ articles to show up there, you should set them to the state "Public (All)" in order for them to be visible on this public front end.